# slicing a datacolumn based on a condition in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis

I have a df,

```
    A    B
0   a    1.0
1   b,c  2.0
2
3   c,d  NaN
```

I am trying to slice `df["A"] when df["B"] is NaN or empty space " "` , I failed in slicing it by (,) Please help me to achieve it, my desired output is,

out_df,

```
    A    B
0   a    1.0
1   b,c  2.0
2
3   c    NaN
```

Comment: Is expected output OK?

Comment: What is the difference between input and output? They are exactly same?

Comment: sorry @Bharath , I edited my expected output, pls check

Comment: @pyd is my solution helpful?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `np.where` i.e

```
df['new'] = np.where((pd.isnull(df['B']))|(df['B']==''), df['A'].str.split(',').str[0], df['A'])
```

or `df.where` i.e

```
df['A'].where((pd.notnull(df['B']))|(df['B']==''), df['A'].str.split(',').str[0])
```

```
    A    B  new
0    a    1    a
1  b,c    2  b,c
2               
3  c,d  NaN    c
```

Comment: thanks for the solution, but why are you always starts with np.where :P

Comment: All about quickness, its faster than `df.where` so

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need conditions chained with `|`, but for check multiple whitespaces is better first convert column to `string` (because possible mixed types - numeric with strings), then [`strip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.strip.html) for convert one or more whitespaces to empty strings:

```
df = df.loc[df['B'].isnull() | (df['B'].astype(str).str.strip() == ''),  'A']
print (df)
2       
3    c,d
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Alternative solution with [`str.match`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.match.html):

```
df = df.loc[df['B'].isnull() | (df['B'].astype(str).str.match('\s+')),  'A']
```

EDIT:

```
df['A'] = df['A'].mask(df['B'].isnull() | (df['B'].astype(str).str.strip() == ''), 
                       df['A'].str.split(',').str[0])
print (df)
     A    B
0    a  1.0
1  b,c  2.0
2          
3    c  NaN
```

Comment: sorry @jezrael,, I edited my expected output pls check now